# Unity: Instantiate prefabs from array, set a tag to them all, wait 2 seconds and destroy every tagged object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to create a script (in javascript but C# is preferable) to do the following steps:

(1) Create a clone of the main camera;
(1) instantiate prefabs from an array set in the editor;
(2) set a tag (the same one) to all of these instantiated gameobjects;
(3) wait for 1 seconds;
(4) destroy every game object that holds the tag set in (2) and also destroy the cloned camera.

I have came up with the following code but it doesnt work. Can anyone help?

**Code Updated**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PreLoader : MonoBehaviour {
    //Array of Objects To Spawn
        public GameObject[] objectsToSpawn;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpawnItemsFromArray());
        }

        IEnumerator SpawnItemsFromArray() //You can name this however you like
        {
            //Instantiates another camera as a GameObject (easy access to Components and removal of Camera)
            GameObject cam1 = Instantiate(GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera"), Vector3.zero, Quaternion.FromToRotation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 1))) as GameObject;
            //Gets AudioListener Component and disables it
            cam1.GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled = false;

            float space = 1;
            float originalSpace = -3;

            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSpawn.Length; i++)
            {
                //You'll have to Instantiate as a GameObject to change its tag
                GameObject go = Instantiate(objectsToSpawn[i], new Vector3(originalSpace, 0, 10.0f), transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                originalSpace += space;
                //Changes the tag to "Holder"
                go.tag = "Holder";

                //This will change the tag of the GameObject that this script is attached too
                //gameObject.tag = "Holder"; 
            }
            //Waits for 2 Sec
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

            //This will destroy (new Camera) and all that have tag "Holder"
            GameObject[] goDestroy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Holder");
            foreach (GameObject goHolder in goDestroy) Destroy(goHolder);
            Destroy(cam1);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the actual results are and what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: Desired result: Instantiate prefabs for x seconds in a newly created cam and then destroy the prefabs and the cam; What is happening: Prefabs are instantiated but not destroyed. Camera is also not destroyed. Draw count start climbing like crazy: 500 draws and 70K batched. There are only 4 prefabs in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `yield WaitForSeconds(2);` only works inside `IEnumerator`. That is called with `StartCoroutine(**IEnumeratorMethodName**());`

You asked for C# code so I hope this helps: (Good luck)

```
void Start () 
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnItemsFromArray());
}

IEnumerator SpawnItemsFromArray() //You can name this however you like
{
    //Instantiates another camera as a GameObject (easy access to Components and removal of Camera)
    GameObject cam1 = Instantiate(GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera"), Vector3.zero, Quaternion.FromToRotation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 1))) as GameObject;
    //Gets AudioListener Component and disables it
    cam1.GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled = false;
    //If you added this script to the Main Camera uncomment line below and add the appropriate script name to it
    //cam1.GetComponent<**ScriptName**>().enabled = false; //This will make sure the new instantiated Camera doesn't run this script (Otherwise lots of cameras/GameObjects will be spawned

    float space = 1;
    float originalSpace = -3;

    for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSpawn.Length; i++)
    {
        //You'll have to Instantiate as a GameObject to change its tag
        GameObject go = Instantiate(objectsToSpawn[i], new Vector3(originalSpace, 0, 10.0f), transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        originalSpace += space;
        //Changes the tag to "Holder"
        go.tag = "Holder";

        //This will change the tag of the GameObject that this script is attached too
        //gameObject.tag = "Holder"; 
    }
    //Waits for 2 Sec
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    //This will destroy (new Camera) and all that have tag "Holder"
    GameObject[] goDestroy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Holder");
    foreach (GameObject goHolder in goDestroy) Destroy(goHolder);
    Destroy(cam1);
}
```

Comment: I updated your code with the Array of Objects. But it is not working. It does instantiate the prefabs but it is not destroying them. Actually it seems like is drawing them over and over again because the draw count start going up like crazy ... in 5 secs it does more than 1000 drawcalls when my game doesnt do more than 30.

Comment: That is very strange. Are you calling `StartCoroutine(SpawnItemsFromArray());` inside of the `void Update(){}` method by any chance (or any method that updates each frame)? I'll get back to you soon after I test out the code again. Just out of curiosity how many prefabs are you instantiating?

Comment: If you are placing the script onto the Main Camera itself be sure to disable the script on the new camera that you instantiate (Otherwise it will run that cameras script so on). Right after disabling the AudioListener add this line `cam1.GetComponent<**ThisScriptName**>().enabled = false;`. You don't have to add the ending (.cs)